# Sitecore Powershell: items with multiple fields with the same name

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I am trying to retrieve the "Languages" field using the following syntax:

```
Get-Item master: -Query "<my query>" |
    Show-ListView -property `
    "First Name",
    @{Label="Languages"; Expression={$_.Languages}}
```

Which returns, quite correctly, the Sitecore field "Languages" recording the item's language.
The field that I care about, however, is a Multilist which is also called Languages and is listed under a specific Template Section (called "Background").

**Question**

Is there a way to retrieve an Item's field when another field has the same name?

Answer (score 4):

SPE Drive provider will attempt to remedy this situation with prepending the field name with an underscore. It will do it as many times as needed to achieve uniqueness for each field. in your case to get to the `Languages` field you need to address the field as `_Languages` so the following should yield results you're expecting

```
Get-Item master: -Query "<my query>" |
    Show-ListView -property `
    "First Name",
    @{Label="Languages"; Expression={$_._Languages}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't sure as well, but it seems like you can't use the same field's name.

A small test that I've ran to make sure it's true:

```
Get-Process | select name,cpu,@{n='cpu';e={'lala'}}
```

The error message I'm getting:

```
select : The property cannot be processed because the property "cpu" already 
exists.
```

Comment: What does "e" stands for in the query you posted?

Comment: Because certainly can't have the same key in a dictionary / hashtable

Comment: Name and Expression ('n' and 'e'). You can read more about this here: http://www.leporelo.eu/blog.aspx?id=how-to-specify-computed-property-in-select-object

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
    `Get-Item master: -Query "<my query>" |
    Show-ListView -property 
    "First Name",
    @{Label="Languages"; Expression={$_.Fields["<ID of the field you really want>"].Value}}`

Comment: What is the ID of a field?

Comment: In the template definition in Sitecore each field has a Guid ID associated with it. The Sitecore API will return the value based on this ID. The .Languages that's happening in Sitecore PowerShell is just a facade to the Sitecore API, so just manually accessing the API will solve the issue.

Comment: If you go to the template definition for the template that the field you want comes from, and expand it to show its children, then the children of the section you want, you'll find the field item. Take THAT item's ID and you're all set